# How do you generate data from a file in scalacheck?

Tags: scalacheck, property-based-testing

I want to run scalacheck on a sample dataset that I have in a file. How do I create a generator that reads data from this file and allows me to check a property on it?

Answer (score 0):

You could read in all the data in advance and then use

```
Gen.oneOf(dataSet)
```

to randomly choose one of the values in the set.

If however the data set is too big to read in at once you could just generate the access index using

```
Gen.choose(1, setSize)
```

and read only the selected entry.

Comment: on the second approach. With the second approach i still can only read a subset of data right? Not the whole dataset

Comment: So you want to test against all entries in the file? That would be parameterized testing. I don’t know if that’s supported by Scalacheck.